If an operator is defined over a Schauder basis then it's well defined
We know that in the finite dimensional case, given a linear operator $T:V\to W$ such that $V$ is finite dimensional, then defining $T$ over the basis of $V$ determines $T$ completely so $T$ is well defined, my question is if the same holds for a Schauder basis meaning that given a separable Hilbert space $H$ and $f:H\to \mathbb{R}$ if we define $f$ on the Schauder, then is $f$  well defined?
My motivation is to see whether it is the same for Schauder basis as in the Hamel basis.

I'm assuming you require $f$ to be linear.
If you do not require $f$ to be continuous this always works, yes. Since the vectors in a Schauder basis are linearly independent you automatically get an linear extension $f_0: H_0 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ where $H_0$ denotes the span of the Schauder basis. By considering possible linear extensions $f': H' \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, $H_0\subseteq H' \subseteq H$, of $f_0$, you can apply Zorn's lemma to get a linear extension $f: H\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$.
If you require the extension to be continuous things get trickier.
For example, if the Schauder basis is an orthonormal basis $\{e_n\}_{n\geq 1}$ and $f$ is a continuous extension, we have $f(\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \alpha_n e_n)=\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\alpha_n f(e_n)$ for all sequences $\{\alpha_n\}_n\in \ell^2$. In particular $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\alpha_nf(e_n)$ should converge for all $\{\alpha_n\}_n\in \ell^2$ which already implies that $\{f(e_n)\}_n\in \ell^2$. So there you have it, if $\{f(e_n)\}_n\notin \ell^2$, there does not exist a continuous extension.
